# Python Redirecting

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a Password checker and generator. So first i need to make a menu to tell if the user wants to check or generate or password. But I'm having a bit of a problem to redirect the user to their choice.

I've tried to use this 'if main = name' but that doesn't even work. I've also tried to place the 'def' above the all the other text. But wouldn't work because it would display that def first instead of displaying the menu

```
import sys, os

def mainmenu():
        print()
print("________________________________________________________")
print("Hello and welcome to the password checker and generator.")
print("________________________________________________________")
input()
print("Mainmenu")
input()
print("Press 1 to Check a password.")
print("Press 2 to Generate a password.")
print("Press 3 to quit.")
UserOp = int(input("What is your choice?:"))  

if UserOp == 1:
    checkpass()

elif UserOp == 2:
    generatepass()

elif UserOp == 3:
     sys.exit(0)

else:
    print("This option is seen to be invalid.")
    mainmenu()

def checkpass():
    print()
print("You have chosen to check a password.")

def generatepass():
    print()

print("You have chosen to generate a password.")
```

So what I'm trying to re-arrange or add code to make the program display the menu first then redirect the user to their designated options.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you just typed it in wrong on stackoverflow it looks like none of your initial print options are in the mainmenu function
It’s looks at tho the options are also outside of the functions and mix in with your other functions

Comment: thanks man, i dont actually know what you did but im guessing i have to tab the rest of the code when its supposed to be in a def

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation, pieces of your code are out of places where they should be.

```
import sys, os

def mainmenu():
    print()
    print("________________________________________________________")
    print("Hello and welcome to the password checker and generator.")
    print("________________________________________________________")
    input()
    print("Mainmenu")
    input()
    print("Press 1 to Check a password.")
    print("Press 2 to Generate a password.")    
    print("Press 3 to quit.")
    UserOp = int(input("What is your choice?:"))

    if UserOp == 1:
        checkpass()

    elif UserOp == 2:
        generatepass()

    elif UserOp == 3:
        sys.exit(0)

    else:
        print("This option is seen to be invalid.")
        mainmenu()


def checkpass():
    print()
    print("You have chosen to check a password.")


def generatepass():
    print()
    print("You have chosen to generate a password.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainmenu()
```